# How to write a method that prints out a list of days an entree will be served based on user input?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I know i may get lots of down votes for this, but I'm just a little alright in `c#`, but still have a while to go. Id really appreciate if someone could help me. My application is mostly a contained in a class called `dailyMenu`. The class has these fields:

```
public class dailyMenu
{
    private string day = "";
    private int date = 0;
    public string entree { get; private set; }
    private double price;
    private double calories;
    static int initalDate = 1;
    static string[] daysOfWeek = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
    static string[] entrees = {"Beef Tenderloin Fresco", "Madagascar Filet Mignon", "Filet Mignon", " Lobster Ravioli", "Asian Infused Braised Beef", "New Age Chicken Cordon Bleu", "Short Ribs", " Beef Wellington",
        "Fajitas", "Bacon Cheeseburger", " Beef Burgandy", "Spagehetti"};
    static double[] entreePrices = { 5.99, 7.99, 6.99, 4.50, 9.99, 10.29, 5.67, 8.99, 3.99, 4.78, 10, 79, 6.98 };
    static int[] entreeMealCaloricVal = { 999, 1288, 770, 699, 450, 999, 1500, 873, 911, 1011, 777, 500 };
```

These are my properties:

```
public string Day
{
    get { return day; }
    set { day = value; }
}
public int Date
{
    get { return date; }
    set { date = value; }
}
public string Entree
{
    get { return entree; }
    set { entree = value; }
}
public double Price
{
    get { return price; }
    set { price = value; }
}
public double Calories
{
    get { return calories; }
    set { calories = value; }
}
```

Next, I had to create objects of my `dailymenu` class in my main method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dailyMenu[,] daysOfMonth = new dailyMenu[4, 5];
    for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.GetLength(0); column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.GetLength(1); row++)
        {
            dailyMenu dm = new dailyMenu();
            daysOfMonth[column, row] = dm;
            Console.WriteLine(dm.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And now, i am trying to come up with a function that after the user enters in one of the above entrees, the console will print out all days in which the entree that was entered will be served on. It also takes a 2D array as an argument.
This is what I've come up with so far.

```
static void entreeSearch(dailyMenu[,] daysOfMonth)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PLease enter the entree you'd like to search for today :)");
    string response = Console.ReadLine();
    response = response.ToUpper();

    for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.GetLength(0); column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.GetLength(1); row++)
        {
            if (response ==)
            {
                dailyMenu dm = new dailyMenu();
                daysOfMonth[column, row] = dm;
                Console.WriteLine(dm.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need to fill in what day has what entree. Currently you are initializing to default values, so every single day's entree is `null`. But once you fix that, this should work:

```
    static void entreeSearch(dailyMenu [,] daysOfMonth)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("PLease enter the entree you'd like to search for today :)");
        string response = Console.ReadLine ();
        response = response.ToUpper ();

        for (int column = 0; column < daysOfMonth.GetLength(0); column++) 
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < daysOfMonth.GetLength(1); row++) 
            {
                dailyMenu dailyMenuAtThisRowAndColumn = daysOfMonth[column, row];
                if (dailyMenuAtThisRowAndColumn.Entree.ToUpper() == response)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine($"Entree {response} was found on day {daysOfMonth[column, row].Day}");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: See it's funny now that i look at that it makes sense, but could you explain to me how it works?

Comment: You don't know how it works? Did you not write the code you posted? `daysOfMonth` is an array of `dailyMenu` objects. You fill in that array with this line, `daysOfMonth[column, row] = dm`. To set each day's entree you could do before that line, `dm.Entree = "Spagehetti";`. Every `dailyMenu` object has a string property named `Entree`, so we just compare that day's Entree with the response, as shown in my answer. I'll edit it to make it more clear that the `daysOfMonth` array contains `dailyMenu` objects.

Comment: i do understand and this is my code, i just like to look at a good explanation of things, but thank you very much

Comment: @NnachetaNnyagu yes, read my answer again. You have not initialized any of the Entree's. You make a new daily menu in your code, `dailyMenu dm = new dailyMenu();`, but you do not assign any properties to it, such as `dm.Entree = "Spagehetti"`. So as it stands, every single `dm.Entree` is `null` until you assign it to something. This will cause `if (dailyMenuAtThisRowAndColumn.Entree.ToUpper()` to throw a null error because it's trying to to do `.ToUpper()` on a null object which isn't allowed. P.s., that's spelled wrong, it's "Spaghetti".